# Kafka Stream Suppress is not producing output after Windowing

Tags: apache-kafka, java-stream, apache-kafka-streams

I am windowing the incoming objects from the stream enviroment, collecting and printing it. 
Using kafka suppress to avoid intermediate results.

After using suppress I am not able to any output. If I comment out the suppress the code works fine but prints intermediate results.

```
import com.savk.workout.kafka.streams.kafkastreamsworkout.config.ConfigUtils;
import com.savk.workout.kafka.streams.kafkastreamsworkout.model.Observation;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Suppressed;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TimeWindows;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerde;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Properties;

@Component
public class ObservationAnalyser {

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder;
        KStream<String, Observation> observationKStream;

        String observationSerde = ConfigUtils.getObservationSerde();        //TODO : Should we move to a JSON Serde?
        Properties kafkaStreamProperties = ConfigUtils.getKafkaStreamConfig();
        kafkaStreamProperties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        kafkaStreamProperties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, observationSerde);

        //JsonSerde<ObservationCollector> observationCollectorJsonSerde = new JsonSerde<>(ObservationCollector.class);

        streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
        observationKStream = streamsBuilder.stream(ConfigUtils.KAFKA_SOURCE_TOPIC);
        observationKStream
                .groupByKey()
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMillis(ConfigUtils.ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLISECONDS)))
                .aggregate(
                        () -> new ObservationCollector(),
                        (key, value, observationCollector) -> observationCollector.addObservations(value),
                        Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), new JsonSerde<>(ObservationCollector.class))
                )
                .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))    //AFTER COMMENTING THIS LINE, I CAN SEE THE OUTPUT
                .toStream((key, value) -> key.key())
                .foreach((key, observationCollector) -> {
                    System.out.println("Key :: " + key);
                    for(Observation observation : observationCollector.getObservations())   {
                        System.out.println("Observation :: " + observation);
                    }
                });

        KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(streamsBuilder.build(), kafkaStreamProperties);
        kafkaStreams.start();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(kafkaStreams::close));
    }

}
```

I am not able to figure out what is issue/problem or finding any resources to troubleshoot.

Comment: FYI, there is a producer which keeps producing data every 4 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default "grace period" is 1 day (for backward compatibility reasons if `suppress()` is not used). Hence, the window will not close before event time advanced by 1 day.

You may want to reduce the grace period (and maybe also the retention time) via

- `TimeWindows.of(..).grace(...)`
- `Materialized.with(...).withRetentionTime(...)`

Comment: .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMillis(ConfigUtils.ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLISECONDS)).grace(Duration.ofMillis(0)))

Comment: Can you please provide the resource link for this information?

Comment: May I know where/how to use "Materialized.with(...).withRetentionTime(...)" ?

Comment: I guess there is a limited amount of documentation unfortunately... The original design document of `suppress()` might help: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-328%3A+Ability+to+suppress+updates+for+KTables -- for the retetnion time, it only make sense to have a larger retention time than required, if you use "Interactive Queries" -- I am not sure atm from the top of my head if setting a grace period will set a smaller retention time automatically. If not, you can reduce the storage footprint by setting a smaller retention time.